# PHP Gearman Worker / Client does not work

Tags: php, gearman

I am trying to execute [this minimal example](http://gearman.org/getting-started/#client) of a gearman Job Server with php:

**worker.php:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("reverse", "my_reverse_function");
echo "Starting Worker...\n";
while ($worker->work());

function my_reverse_function($job)
{
  return strrev($job->workload());
}
?>
```

**client.php:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
echo "Starting Client...\n";
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
print $client->doNormal("reverse", "Hello World!");
?>
```

I am trying it in the console with `php worker.php` which gives the output *"Starting Worker..."*
Then I am trying `php client.php` (in another console-window) which gives the output *Starting Client...* (no more). However I am expecting the output "*!dlroW olleH*" or at least a suitable error message....
The code following gives me the output: *1.0.6*, so I am assuming, the gearman software is installed correctly. I am on a debian 8.1 btw.

```
<?php
echo gearman_version();
?>
```

What is wrong? Why does my Gearman Worker and / or Client not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the IP (instead of the default value "localhost"), solved the issue.

```
$worker->addServer("127.0.0.1");
```